# Concurrent modification of element children

Tags: dom, dart

What is the "best" method for inserting new elements after each child to a given element (`element`).

The following naturally gives a *Concurrent modification* exception

```
element.children.forEach((Element child){
  var new_child = new DivElement();
  element.insertBefore(new_child, child);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to avoid `ConcurrentModificationError` is to *duplicate* the list by calling [toList()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/Iterable.html#toList) before doing modifications.

```
element.children.toList().forEach((Element child){
  var new_child = new DivElement();
  element.insertBefore(new_child, child);
});
```